# spring mvc form bean convertion from string to long

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a very simple crud. It´s composed by a bean that represent form data. I have a field with a long value. In jsp i write this: `<form:hidden path="id"/>`. When i submit the form i get HTTP Status 400 error.

in short when a submit a long value spring mvc can not convert it to long to construct my form object.

the flow is simple: the user click edit over e company. the controller via a service retrieve the company, then the view is rendered, and finaly the user submit changes.. but well when the long value is submit i got the error.

The debug information tells me this:

```
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver [DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String ar.com.held.controller.CompanyController.edit(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model)]: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "save"
```

here is the code:

my form bean:

```
public class CompanyForm {

    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotBlank
    private String addressStreet;
    @NotBlank
    private String addressCity;
    @NotBlank
    private String addressState;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddressStreet() {
        return addressStreet;
    }

    public void setAddressStreet(String addressStreet) {
        this.addressStreet = addressStreet;
    }

    public String getAddressCity() {
        return addressCity;
    }

    public void setAddressCity(String addressCity) {
        this.addressCity = addressCity;
    }

    public String getAddressState() {
        return addressState;
    }

    public void setAddressState(String addressState) {
        this.addressState = addressState;
    }

}
```

my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"edit/{companyId}"})
    public String edit(@PathVariable Long companyId, Model model){
        CompanyForm form = new CompanyForm();
        if(companyId!=null){
            Company company = companyService.find(companyId);
            if(company!=null)
                modelMapper.map(company, form);
        }
        model.addAttribute("form", form);
        return "company/edit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"new"})
    public String edit(Model model){
        return this.edit(null, model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="save", method={RequestMethod.POST})
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("form") @Valid CompanyForm companyForm, BindingResult result){
        if(result.hasErrors())
            return "company/edit";
        Company company;
        if(companyForm.getId()!=null)
            company = companyService.find(companyForm.getId());
        else
            company = new Company();
        modelMapper.map(companyForm, company);
        companyService.save(company, getLoggedUser());
        return "redirect:list";
    }
```

my jsp:

```
<form:form method="post" action="save" modelAttribute="form" cssClass="form-horizontal" >
        <fieldset>

            <form:hidden path="id"/>
            ++++  others fields +++
            <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary btn-large"/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form:form>
```

debug information

```
2012-02-17 18:17:45 AntPathRequestMatcher [DEBUG] Checking match of request : '/companies/edit/save'; against '/resources/**'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository [DEBUG] Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@bcc22d3c: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bcc22d3c: Principal: ar.com.held.auth.UserDetails@1421801; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 93B19E8B81EBB7F4BFEECF4FFFC46593; Granted Authorities: COMPANY_OWNER'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [DEBUG] SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bcc22d3c: Principal: ar.com.held.auth.UserDetails@1421801; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 93B19E8B81EBB7F4BFEECF4FFFC46593; Granted Authorities: COMPANY_OWNER'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 AntPathRequestMatcher [DEBUG] Checking match of request : '/companies/edit/save'; against '/companies/*'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterSecurityInterceptor [DEBUG] Public object - authentication not attempted
2012-02-17 18:17:45 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2012-02-17 18:17:45 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing POST request for [/Held/companies/edit/save]
2012-02-17 18:17:45 RequestMappingHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Looking up handler method for path /companies/edit/save
2012-02-17 18:17:45 RequestMappingHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Returning handler method [public java.lang.String ar.com.held.controller.CompanyController.edit(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model)]
2012-02-17 18:17:45 DefaultListableBeanFactory [DEBUG] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'companyController'
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:17:45 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2012-02-17 18:17:45 ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver [DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String ar.com.held.controller.CompanyController.edit(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model)]: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "save"
2012-02-17 18:17:45 ResponseStatusExceptionResolver [DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String ar.com.held.controller.CompanyController.edit(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model)]: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "save"
2012-02-17 18:17:45 DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver [DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String ar.com.held.controller.CompanyController.edit(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model)]: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "save"
2012-02-17 18:17:45 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'spring': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2012-02-17 18:17:45 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Successfully completed request
2012-02-17 18:17:45 ExceptionTranslationFilter [DEBUG] Chain processed normally
2012-02-17 18:17:45 SecurityContextPersistenceFilter [DEBUG] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2012-02-17 18:26:56 AntPathRequestMatcher [DEBUG] Checking match of request : '/companies/edit/save'; against '/resources/**'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository [DEBUG] Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@bcc22d3c: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bcc22d3c: Principal: ar.com.held.auth.UserDetails@1421801; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 93B19E8B81EBB7F4BFEECF4FFFC46593; Granted Authorities: COMPANY_OWNER'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [DEBUG] SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bcc22d3c: Principal: ar.com.held.auth.UserDetails@1421801; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 93B19E8B81EBB7F4BFEECF4FFFC46593; Granted Authorities: COMPANY_OWNER'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 AntPathRequestMatcher [DEBUG] Checking match of request : '/companies/edit/save'; against '/companies/*'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterSecurityInterceptor [DEBUG] Public object - authentication not attempted
2012-02-17 18:26:56 FilterChainProxy [DEBUG] /companies/edit/save reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2012-02-17 18:26:56 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing POST request for [/Held/companies/edit/save]
2012-02-17 18:26:56 RequestMappingHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Looking up handler method for path /companies/edit/save
2012-02-17 18:26:56 RequestMappingHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Returning handler method [public java.lang.String ar.com.held.controller.CompanyController.edit(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model)]
2012-02-17 18:26:56 DefaultListableBeanFactory [DEBUG] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'companyController'
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initializing new StandardEnvironment
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2012-02-17 18:26:56 StandardEnvironment [DEBUG] Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2012-02-17 18:26:56 ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver [DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String ar.com.held.controller.CompanyController.edit(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model)]: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "save"
2012-02-17 18:26:56 ResponseStatusExceptionResolver [DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String ar.com.held.controller.CompanyController.edit(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model)]: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "save"
2012-02-17 18:26:56 DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver [DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String ar.com.held.controller.CompanyController.edit(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model)]: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "save"
2012-02-17 18:26:56 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'spring': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2012-02-17 18:26:56 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Successfully completed request
2012-02-17 18:26:56 ExceptionTranslationFilter [DEBUG] Chain processed normally
2012-02-17 18:26:56 SecurityContextPersistenceFilter [DEBUG] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was here:

when i edit a company i'm pointing to /companies/edit/{id}

```
<form:form method="post" action="save" modelAttribute="form" cssClass="form-horizontal" >
```

so, when i submit the form the url looks like: /companies/edit/save and my controller expect /companies/save..

so, i have to indicate the absolute path for the action attribute in form tag. Like Here:

```
<form:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/companies/save" modelAttribute="form" cssClass="form-horizontal" >
```

and problem solve.. it was a url problem.